# Terraform, "ignore_changes" and sub-blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I have a AWS CodePipeline configured in a terraform file, like this:

```
resource {
    name = "Cool Pipeline"
    ...

    stage {
        name = "Source"
        ...

        action {
            name = "Source"
            ...

            configuration {
                Owner = "Me"
                Repo = "<git-repo-uri>"
                Branch = develop
                OAuthToken = "b3287d649a28374e9283c749cc283ad74"
            }
        }
    }

    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = "OAuthToken"
    }
}
```

The reason for ignoring the token, is that the AWS API doesn't show that token to terraform, instead AWS API outputs this with `aws codepipeline get-pipeline <name>`:

```
"pipeline": {
    "stages": {
        "name": "Source",
        "actions": {
            "configuration": {
                "OAuthToken": "****"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result is, when I perform the `terraform plan`it shows me it wants to update that token, like so:

```
module.modulename.aws_codepipeline.codepipeline
      stage.0.action.0.configuration.%:          "3" => "4"
      stage.0.action.0.configuration.OAuthToken: "" => "b3287d649a28374e9283c749cc283ad74"
```

My question is, how can I get the `ignore_changes` to take effect? I've tried this without any success:

```
ignore_changes = ["OAuthToken"]
ignore_changes = ["oauthtoken"]
ignore_changes = ["stage.action.configuration.OAuthToken"]
```

All examples I've found googling just shows how to ignore on the same block level.

(The token is this text is fake.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This syntax, as hinted by `terraform plan` output, solved the problem:

```
ignore_changes = [
    "stage.0.action.0.configuration.OAuthToken",
    "stage.0.action.0.configuration.%"
]
```

Another way to solve it is to add the `GITHUB_TOKEN` system environment variable, with the token as the value. This way you do not need the `ignore_changes` directive in the tf files.

Comment: Glad that you found a way to solve this but this is a bug in the resource and should be raised as an issue. You can raise it [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues) if you're happy to do that so it fixes it for other people and means you can remove your `ignore_changes` stanza.

Comment: Since I wrote this question, I found from documentation that you can also use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` system environment which then stops it from happening.

I mean, AWS doesn't give you the value of the github token, for security reasons, so how would terraform know the value has not been changed?

Comment: This helped me solve a problem with Azure app services getting lots of app settings added by the infrastructure (for example, Azure DevOps deployments) that i don't want to be affect TF plans. Adding the filtered this setting out of plan diffs `lifecycle {
    ignore_changes  = [
      "app_settings.APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION"
    ]
  }`

Answer (score 14):

This syntax is deprecated

```
ignore_changes = [
    "stage.0.action.0.configuration.OAuthToken",
    "stage.0.action.0.configuration.%"
]
```

But the new one is ignored in v1.0.0 for some reason

```
ignore_changes = [
  stage[0].action[0].configuration.OAuthToken,
  stage[0].action[0].configuration,
]
```

Comment: I can confirm that I'm also experiencing an issue with ignore_changes not being taken into consideration so I've opened a Github issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28953

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered a similar case and I resolved as follows:

```
ignore_changes = [
   stage[0].action[0].configuration["OAuthToken"]
]
```